# Open a NEW WINDOW in CHROME in INCOGNITO Mode from terminal with specified URLS

Tags: macos, google-chrome, terminal, iterm

I need help on completing a bash script which should be able to

- Open New Window (Not tabs) in Chrome (Or chrome canary)
- Open each new window in **INCOGNITO** Mode
- Open the specified **URL** in script

My script is as:

```
# Open up the urls in Canary
# but in NEW_TABS not in NEW_WINDOWS
# NOT in INCOGNITO Mode either
open -a "Google Chrome Canary" http://example1.com --args --incognito
open -a "Google Chrome Canary" http://example2.com --args --incognito
open -a "Google Chrome Canary" http://example3.com --args --incognito
open -a "Google Chrome Canary" http://example4.com --args --incognito

# New incognito tabs open up but aren't opening up the urls
open -na "Google Chrome Canary" http://example1.com --args --incognito
open -na "Google Chrome Canary" http://example2.com --args --incognito
```

I am on OSX and using Iterm.
I found it amusing not to find any solution for this kind of requirement on internet. Let me know your suggestions.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
open -na "Google Chrome" --args -incognito example.com
```

This works if your use case is to open up a link.

For my case I was trying to open up a html file `index.html` but I think it was auto prefixed with `http://` so it opened up the file as `http://index.hml` instead. Hopefully the above helps for you though.

Answer (score 1):

in your windows open cmd and type this

```
start Chrome --incognito http://google.com/
```

here URL is optional