# Mac Os: How to open url in browser incognito mode from the command line?

Tags: macos, command-line, firefox, safari, private-browsing

I'm looking for a universal way to open provided URL from the command line in default browsers incognito mode.

As a fall back scenario, I'm ok with some specific browser like Chromium, Firefox or Safari.

Answer (score 3):

From [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1292697/394752):
"Open a new window in CHROME in INCOGNITO Mode from terminal with specified URLS"

```
open -na "Google Chrome" --args -incognito example.com
```

Comment: Ok, but what does it?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any generally applicable way of doing this.

Chrome's AppleScript interface is not very good, but it can be convinced into creating a new incognito window with a specified URL:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Google Chrome" to make tab with properties {URL:"http://www.example.com"} at (make window with properties {mode:"incognito"})'
```

This will always create a new window, but at least it will work. (Substitute your URL for the example given in this code.)

The AppleScript suites available for Safari and Firefox are both even worse; neither one provides any way to create a private browsing window.